# How to get to the Church of the Holy Sepulchre for Easter?

Tags: religion, jerusalem, easter

I am an Orthodox Christian, and one of my dreams is to visit Jerusalem and the Church of the Holy Sepulchre for an Easter, and see the holy fire.

Finding a flight and hotel is easy, but what do I need to get to the church? I know that I need to get some tickets. How do I get a ticket? Who sells them? Do I need anything else?

Comment: https://churchoftheholysepulchre.net/visitor-information/

Comment: @Max Thanks, but that info is not correct. There are tickets. [Here](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293983-i2582-k3242001-Tickets_to_attend_the_Garden_Tomb_service_on_Easter_Sunday-Jerusalem_Jerusalem_District.html) is some info, but links are dead.

Comment: I never saw tickets. Note: to enter to the church is easy. If you want to participate to a mass, you may need some sort of ticket to get a sitting place. But in this case, you should check with the organizer. Different parts have different custodians, but according schedule, others could use it. It is complex. Start checking in your country, to get relevant contacts.

Comment: It is the site of the Church, unless proven otherwise it should be canon; do you have a link where it states you need tickets?

Comment: Note to your link: there are different "Easter times". Careful not to choose the wrong one.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I am organizing the trip for me.

Comment: @BЈовић: it is not about organizing, but getting the good contacts. It is not really a commercial place, so "invitations" are sent to various bishops, etc. On your completely own: go few days before, familiarize with the numerous churches in the church, with timetable and place you can be (there are many very good standing places). Go very early. If you are praying, guards will not move you away (standing places). Just be discrete. Having some good (possibly religious) books help to wait. Many Russians give money to custodian (for the church), so it could be expected on some Orthodox parts.

Comment: @BЈовић Your comments link leads to recommendations for guided tours. See my answer.

Comment: You aren't Palestinian are you? There absolutely are restrictions on Palestinians visiting Old Jerusalem at Easter.

Comment: @DJClayworth No, I am not.

Answer (score 2):

Entry to the Church of the Holy Sepulchre is free and unlimited at all times. [The church's own website says this.](https://churchoftheholysepulchre.net/visitor-information/). No ticket is required.

This allows you to look round the church and to attend a service. But many people want to do more than that, in which case you can consider taking a guided tour. The church itself recommends a number of guided tours, and the TripAdvisor links that you posted in comments leads to a very similar list. They require paid tickets, and these are probably the tickets you are thinking of.

To summarize:

- If you want to enter the Church of the Holy Sepulchre, either to attend a service or simply to look round, you can do so any time it is open without paying.
- If you also want to take a guided tour of the church you will need to buy a ticket and pay for it.

Comment: I was told that for the Easter I need some kind of a ticket, and the link I posted tells the same. I will investigate further, from the people that went (when I find them).

Comment: The chat you link to is over ten years old.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find much info online, that is why I asked here.